# Cannot reshape non-existent tensors

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I built this Linear Regression model and I am getting this error-

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_experimental_distribute': None, '_task_id': 0, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
graph_options {
  rewrite_options {
    meta_optimizer_iterations: ONE
  }
}
, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x0000026083C22EB8>, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_model_dir': 'train1', '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_master': '', '_num_worker_replicas': 1, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_session_creation_timeout_secs': 7200, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_evaluation_master': '', '_train_distribute': None, '_is_chief': True, '_service': None, '_task_type': 'worker', '_device_fn': None, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_protocol': None}
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-3fa8c64443b5> in <module>
     54         shuffle=False)
     55 
---> 56 TB_train = estimator.train(input_fn=train_input, steps=1000)
     57 TB_test = estimator.evaluate(eval_input,steps=None)
     58 # TB_predict = estimator.predict(test_input)

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    368 
    369       saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 370       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    371       logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    372       return self

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1158       return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1159     else:
-> 1160       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1161 
   1162   def _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners):

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1188       worker_hooks.extend(input_hooks)
   1189       estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(
-> 1190           features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
   1191       global_step_tensor = training_util.get_global_step(g)
   1192       return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, config)
   1146 
   1147     logging.info('Calling model_fn.')
-> 1148     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
   1149     logging.info('Done calling model_fn.')
   1150 

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\linear.py in _model_fn(features, labels, mode, config)
   1391           partitioner=partitioner,
   1392           config=config,
-> 1393           sparse_combiner=sparse_combiner)
   1394 
   1395     super(LinearRegressor, self).__init__(

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\linear.py in _linear_model_fn(features, labels, mode, head, feature_columns, optimizer, partitioner, config, sparse_combiner)
    742           sparse_combiner=sparse_combiner,
    743           )
--> 744       logits = logit_fn(features=features)
    745 
    746       optimizer = optimizers.get_optimizer_instance(

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\linear.py in linear_logit_fn(features)
    421           sparse_combiner=sparse_combiner,
    422           name='linear_model')
--> 423       logits = linear_model(features)
    424       bias = linear_model.bias
    425 

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    845                     outputs = base_layer_utils.mark_as_return(outputs, acd)
    846                 else:
--> 847                   outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    848 
    849             except errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError as e:

c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\autograph\impl\api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    235       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    236         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 237           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    238         else:
    239           raise

ValueError: in converted code:
    relative to c:\users\neelg\tf2_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python:

    feature_column\feature_column_v2.py:706 call
        return self.layer(features)
    feature_column\feature_column_v2.py:540 call
        weight_var=weight_var)
    feature_column\feature_column_v2.py:2411 _create_weighted_sum
        weight_var=weight_var)
    feature_column\feature_column_v2.py:2420 _create_dense_column_weighted_sum
        tensor = array_ops.reshape(tensor, shape=(batch_size, num_elements))
    ops\array_ops.py:131 reshape
        result = gen_array_ops.reshape(tensor, shape, name)
    ops\gen_array_ops.py:8117 reshape
        "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
    framework\op_def_library.py:793 _apply_op_helper
        op_def=op_def)
    util\deprecation.py:507 new_func
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    framework\ops.py:3360 create_op
        attrs, op_def, compute_device)
    framework\ops.py:3429 _create_op_internal
        op_def=op_def)
    framework\ops.py:1773 __init__
        control_input_ops)
    framework\ops.py:1613 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 9 elements to shape [1,6876] (6876 elements) for 'linear/linear_model/linear_model/linear_model/x/Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [1,9], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [1,6876].
```

Since I didn't give it anything amounting to "6876" elements, I deduce the error could be because of a bug in the code, or some problem in Tensorflow itself

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from itertools import *
import keras
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.models import Sequential

training_set_n = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/neelg/Documents/Jupyter/Tic_Tac_cls/tic_tac_train1.csv").values

test_set_n = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/neelg/Documents/Jupyter/Tic_Tac_cls/tic_tac_test.csv").values

prediction_set_n = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/neelg/Documents/Jupyter/Tic_Tac_cls/tic_tac_predict.csv").values

def prepare_data(df):
        X_train = df[:, 0:9]
        y_train = df[:, 9:10]
        return X_train, y_train

X_train, y_train = prepare_data(training_set_n)
X_test, y_test = prepare_data(test_set_n)
x_predict = prediction_set_n[:, 0:9]

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x', shape=X_train.shape)]

estimator = tf.compat.v1.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns, model_dir="train1")

def breaker(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        testX = data[i]
        testX = data
        data[1] = np.array(data)
        return data

RS_X_train = np.array(X_train[0:128])

train_input = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"x" :RS_X_train},
           y = {"y":y_train[0:128]},
           shuffle=True,
           batch_size=1,
           num_epochs=None)

eval_input = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
       x={"x": X_test},
       y=y_test,
       shuffle=False,
       batch_size=1,
       num_epochs=1)

test_input = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x": x_predict},
        batch_size=1,
        num_epochs=1,
        shuffle=False)

TB_train = estimator.train(input_fn=train_input, steps=1000)
TB_test = estimator.evaluate(eval_input,steps=None)
```

I have checked the other parameters, and they seem to be working as expected.So could it be that the model can't process the reshaped data? Or is there any other error involving improperly shaped variables?

Comment: Check the various input and output shapes for your intermediate nodes.

Comment: Also, `764 * 9 = 6876`, which is what the `LinearRegression` is trying to do. (Your train data is of shape `(764, 9)`.)

Comment: @MateenUlhaq If U carefully study the variables, X_train has been splitted toonly 128 values are fed(Which is what the model can accept). So, 6876 is impossible